# How to drop columns and rows with missing values?

Tags: python, pandas

I've been trying to take a `pandas.Dataframe` and drop its rows and columns with missing values simultaneously. While trying to use `dropna` and applying on both axis, I found out that this is no longer supported. So then I tried, using `dropna`, to drop the columns and then drop the rows and vice versa and obviously, the results come out different as the values no longer reflect the initial state accurately.
So to give an example I receive:

```
pandas.DataFrame({"name": ['Alfred', 'Batman', 'Catwoman'],
                   "toy": [numpy.nan, 'Batmobile', 'Bullwhip'],
                   "weapon": [numpy.nan, 'Boomerang', 'Gun']})
```

and return:

```
pandas.DataFrame({"name": ['Batman', 'Catwoman']})
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if all values per columns and for rows use [`DataFrame.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = df.notna()
df0 = df.loc[m.all(1), m.all()]
print (df0)
      name
1    Batman
2  Catwoman
```

Comment: How would you apply this solution if it's needed to drop columns and rows only where *all* their values are missing?

Comment: @EliranZeitouni - simpliest is `df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=0)` or  `df = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)`